# Rewriting all url's with a question mark

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, duplicates

I'm using magento and every url is acessible in two ways for example:

- `http://www.mysite.com/product-item`, and
- `www.mysite.com/product-item?___store=default`

I tried a regular 301 redirect in `.htaccess` but it won't redirect. Does anyone have the code that would automatically redirect all url's with the suffix `?___store=default` back to the clean url's thus avoiding duplicate content issues?

Comment: Please add the code that you tried for your 301 redirect in `.htaccess`.

Comment: It's not really relevant now because I tried it only for a single url and I need the coding that would redirect all url's with the ?___store=default automatically.

Comment: Can't you just turn off 'Add store code to URLs' from the admin?

Comment: @fkim It was off and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?___store=default
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ___store=default
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

depending on how the query string is generated. The reason why a `Redirect 301` probably didn't work is that you can't match against query strings using that statement.